# AJAX JQuery Upload Image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create the process of uploading an image with jquery ajax.
here's my code :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formPicture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body panel-modal-scrol">
        <input type="file" name="picture" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn-saving" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
<script>
$("[name=formPicture]").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'upload_picture.php',
       data: formData, 
       success: function(data){
        console.log(data);                        
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

**upload_picture.php**

```
<?php
$path = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
$file_name   = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$newPath     = "upload/";
move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,$newPath.$file_name);
$insert="INSERT INTO `picture`(`picture`) 
                        VALUES ('$file_name')";
$query=mysql_query($insert);
if($query){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}else{
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}
?>
```

but the error said "Notice:  Undefined index: picture on line 4";
there's something wrong with my code ?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

**1st aprroach:-**

You will need to use formData() for using ajax and ajax calls need a couple of more parameters to be set. Just follow :-

http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

But do check the browser [compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Edit: - Live code(php) + demo - [here](http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/)

**2nd approach:-**

You can also use iframes for uploading images instead of AJAX

http://www.akchauhan.com/upload-image-using-hidden-iframe/

You will get working examples of both approaches as per the server side language you are using(i.e php, rails, java etc)